Can't connect to ASP.NET server running on Raspberry Pi
I'm trying to run a portable build of an ASP.NET application on .net 8 on a Raspberry Pi.
I've got a Raspberry Pi 4 with the latest lite release of Raspberry Pi oS (Bookworm).
And my publishing settings for the app are:
Delete existing files : false 
Configuration : Release
Target Framework : net8.0
Target runtime : Portable

The application starts and outputs this on the Pi:
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /home/pi/dotnet/lora_api

ApplicationSettings.json:
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:21262",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5020",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}

However, I get no response from localhost:5000 / (RaspiLocalAddress):5000
Am I missing anything?

Just to clarify: I configured port 5000 in UFW. I see no open TCP ports when scanning the Pi's local address with nmap, except for the ssh connection I use to access the Pi.

@Pejda pointed out in their comment that Environment.IsDevelopment() is set whenever running under Visual Studio's development server or IIS. The default ASP.NET example for HTTP request API:s have apparently moved both the HTTP request pipeline and the development UI into an if-statment checking if the Environment.IsDevelopment() is set during the app builder.
The solution is to move the service for the HTTP request pipeline outside of said if-statement. In my case, only the request service was needed and not the debugging UI that comes alongside so I left the UI inside the condition:
app.UseSwagger(); //Move this here
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    //app.UseSwagger was previously here
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}


It looks like its listening only from localhost? Try to run server with variable:
ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000


Do I add this to launchsettings.json?

I've tried this as a launch parameter. However, I still get no response from the server. I'll update the initial post to include my project's launch settings file.

The address is probably right, since I now get a file access exception on the PI when I try to connect to a route that accesses local files, unless I run the application as sudo. And if I run as sudo and connect to said route, I no longer get an exception, but the app returns a HTTP 500 code.

In launch settings there is settings for development, not production.
You need to define that elsewhere. for example env variable, as I suggested. MS Docs
It indicates where should server listen to for requests. The request will access your PI even if this settings is bad, only server wont listen to it. It will listen only for requests sent to "http://localhost:5000". That is not a address you're using when connecting from outside of PI.

This did it. The default examples have both the API and the UI packages under an if condition for some reason. I don't need the UI so I left that there, but I put the API package outside the if condition in the builder.
